# Mathematics and Drupal

Tags: forms, webforms, files

I spent the last couple of days searching about my project on google. Reading on blogs and drupal answers. I haven't concluded to a result.

What I want to do:

1. Have a submission form which can be used to upload math equations and text. The form should have the option for Latex input AND using buttons like MathType.
2. Have the option to edit those data after submission.
3. Generate PDF files from the database using Views.

I found that CKEditor with a math plugin is a popular choice, however it stores the data as images. So, I will not have the option to edit it after that. Storing it as Latex could lead to another problem of generating PDF files since Latex is processed on the client and most of the PDF generators I found are server side.

Any ideas since Google didn't help a lot.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/drutex looks promising.

Comment: It would be best to split it up into multiple problems and tackle them separately. For example there is a submission form, a Latex input format of some sort (preferably with WYSIWYG buttons), and generating a PDF in some way (preferably via views).
Those are 3 separate things.